# Multer: fileFilter not working

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm using multer to upload files. everything is goung fine but fileFilter is not working. I've no idea where i'm going wrong.

**routes.js**

```
var multer = require('multer');
// Multer diskStorage setting
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    var typeArray = file.mimetype.split('/');
    var fileType = typeArray[1];
    if (fileType == 'jpg' || fileType == 'png') {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false)
    }
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() + '.jpg');
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
router.post('/add', upload.single('photo'), function(req, res){

    console.log('uploaded');
}
```

Multer also uploads files other than allowed. Any idea?

Comment: is `filFilter:` a typo in the question or in your code?

Comment: OP: be advised that you should accept (/upvote) an answer if it solved your question. thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fileFilter` must be defined in multer's [options object](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#multeropts) rather than diskStorage

```
const uploadFilter = function(req, file, cb) {
    // filter rules here
}

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: uploadFilter,
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads/');
    },
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        const extension = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase();
        const mimetyp = file.mimetype;
        if (
            extension !== '.jpg' ||
            extension !== '.jpeg' ||
            extension !== '.png' ||
            mimetyp !== 'image/png' ||
            mimetyp !== 'image/jpg' ||
            mimetyp !== 'image/jpeg'
        ) {
            cb('error message', true);
        }
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() + '.jpg');
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
router.post('/add', upload.single('photo'), function (req, res) {
    console.log('uploaded');
});
```

i think this will help

Comment: this does not work https://stackoverflow.com/a/56080004/8556127 this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo at your fileFilter; you've named it filFilter.
Could you change your code to the following and tell us if it worked out?

```
var multer = require('multer');
// Multer diskStorage setting
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads/');
  },
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    var typeArray = file.mimetype.split('/');
    var fileType = typeArray[1];
    if (fileType == 'jpg' || fileType == 'png') {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false)
    }
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() + '.jpg');
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
router.post('/add', upload.single('photo'), function(req, res){

    console.log('uploaded');
}
```